# When math and english collide!

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Here is an easy one for you all folks!

121201221 = easy
12121022222211012 = ???

Understand how the first statement is true so you may figure out what ??? is in the second statement might be.

HINT

> Hints are important to define the boundaries of a puzzle. And without proper boundaries, there is no hope of a proper solution.

Comment: Better add a hint earlier else the question will move to _too broad_ section. BTW, does ??? mean its a 3 letter word?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that. There can't be many plausible ways to map 121201221 to EASY.

Comment: is the hint a real hint?

Comment: I thought that with too much explanations or hints that the puzzle would be way too easy. But I got downvoted withing 5 seconds and my puzzle that took me 30 minutes to build up vanished into nothingness. So I edited a little. I hope it won't be too easy now.

Comment: (I am beginning to suspect that actually one maps EASY to 121201221 rather than vice versa.)

Comment: @lois6b it is a real hint but written in a cryptic way that won't give it away too easily(and make it more fun too)

Comment: Unless it is a hint, there might be a typo in the title.

Comment: (looks like it was a typo -- it's been fixed now)

Comment: @Matsmath fixed it. Thanks. The title is not really relevant to the puzzle.

Comment: @Techidiot the ??? offers no specific indications. It simply shows that this is the value to find.

Comment: Getting a feeling that ASCII codes will play crucial here as _e=101_ and _y=121_

Comment: @Techidiot On the other hand a=97 and s=115, which don't fit so well. I'm expecting not-ASCII, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is:

> PUZZLE

How I solved it:

> • Convert each letter to a corresponding number, A=1, B=2,..., Z=26
>  • Convert the number to ternary (base 3) system. Did that because the number only contained digits 0,1,2.
>  • 12=5=E, 1=1=A, 201=19=S, 221=25=Y.
>  • Now the tricky part was to break down the second set of numbers in a way so it forms a coherent word and there are multiple ways of doing so.
>  • In the previous word 221 was letter Y, so pretty obvious that 222 was Z. Two Z in the middle.
>  The next letter could be 1=1=A, 11=4=D or 110=12=L.
>  If its L the last 12 becomes an E.
>  Pretty easy to figure out the first two letters after that.

Comment: I immediately noticed second conversion you made, but I wasn't seeing how to separate it >.<

Comment: Well, I thought it was easy, but that was faster than expected... Good job!

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting. Still new here and having trouble with the spoiler formatting.

Comment: @dcfyj The 222222 in the middle of the number caught my attention. I might have taken much longer if it was another word.

Comment: it is only one of the answers: ABABCBBBBBBACAB is valid too, even though it does not mean anything.